# is there a way to have quarter of a year intervals in the simile timeline javascript widget?

Tags: javascript, timeline, simile

When using [the javascript timeline widget simile](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/), i see there is hour, day, week, month, year intervals.  Is there anyway to have an interval be a quarter of a year?

i am trying to group events into Quarter1, Q2,  Q3, Q4 in 2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Simile wiki](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Main_Page) has some notes on [how to add new intervals](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Timeline/Date_Ranges) to `Timeline.DateTime` by editing `date-time.js` and `labelers.js`. This would be one way to add support for a quarter of a year interval.

Looking at the [source code repository for Simile timeline](http://code.google.com/p/simile-widgets/source/browse/timeline/trunk/src/webapp/api/#api/ext/planning), there is also a `planning` extension to timeline that includes support for `Timeline.PlanningUnit.QUARTER`, which may already do what you want